# Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner for multidomain hosting

Tags: dns, smtp, hosting-services

We are planing for mail hosting, we are going to host multiple customer mail domain on single public IP. Now how i am going to set PTR record per customer? because i have single IP and it has to be single PTR enty.. If my customer running `Mail Test` tool online then he is getting error `Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The forward and reverse DNS need to match.  The name itself does not matter.

For example in my domain (ziobro.info) I have a record:
rack2   IN      A       162.219.7.27

My provider has a record:
27                      PTR     rack2.ziobro.info.
in their corresponding in-addr.arp file.

One of my mail domains (ziobro.rochester.ny.us) has the appropriate MX recod:

```
ziobro.rochester.ny.us. MX      42 rack.ziobro.info.
```

Just repeat the MX record for each mail domain you host.

Ciao,
//Z\